# macOS app can no longer access external resources over Internet after signing it with codesign command

Tags: xcode, macos, unity-game-engine, code-signing

I have built a macOS app bundle using Unity which I intend to submit to the Mac App Store. I followed the instructions for building as mentioned in the Unity documentation, [Delivering your application to the Mac App Store](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-PortToAppleMacStore.html).

I am able to run the Build command for macOS and get a .app bundle for my app. I am also able to launch it and it runs absolutely fine. However, after running the following `codesign` command, the app fails to access any resources over the Internet. The Internet reachability module in my program source code reports that the Internet is un-reachable. This is the `codesign` command line that I am running:

```
codesign -f --deep -s '3rd Party Mac Developer Application: DEVELOPER NAME' --entitlements "GAMENAME.entitlements" "/AppPath/GAMENAME.app"
```

All external resources are accessed over HTTPS. Also, the project's `Info.plist` file has `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` keys added and set to `true`. (This is done by default by Unity.)

It is also worth noting that building a macOS app project in Unity produces the .app bundle. The included `Info.plist` file comes pre-configured with the `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` keys and set to `true`.

I have tried by both retaining and removing the `NSAppTransportSecurity` and `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` keys with no success. I have also tried adding the specific domains under the keys with no success.

I am running the current latest version of all the software, and the same are mentioned below:

1. macOS Catalina 10.15.1
2. Xcode 11.2.1
3. Unity 2019.2.13

My questions are:

- What is it that may be going wrong?
- What other avenues do I have?

I am looking for distributing the app *exclusively* via the Mac App Store for the time being. This is going to be a paid app (if that's relevant).

Comment: @DoctorPangloss Is this a kind of issue that you encountered?

Comment: Is your app sandboxed? For distribution on the Mac App Store it must be. Try enabling the `com.apple.security.network.client` entitlement.

Comment: @TheNextman That was very helpful. I was missing this entitlement. Thank you very much. Kindly consider adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac App Store apps must be [sandboxed](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/). In the sandbox environment, extra entitlements are needed to make network connections.

The entitlements are listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW1). See the section "Enabling Network Access" for this specific issue, which says:

> Xcode’s Network checkboxes in the Summary tab of the target editor let you enable network access for your app.
>
> To enable your app to connect to a server process running on another machine (or on the same machine), enable outgoing network connections.
>
> To enable opening a network listening socket so that other computers can connect to your app, allow incoming network connections.

To allow outgoing network connections, you need to add `com.apple.security.network.client`.